# How to intergate youtube javsacript api in web page

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am working with the youtube api for the first time. I want to implement the the rating api on my website. Here is the code I am using

```
 function videosGetRating(params) {
  params = removeEmptyParams(params); // See full sample for function
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.getRating(params);
  executeRequest(request);
}
```

I am new for the api key. I just want to know how to integrate the api in my webpage? From where I can get url of youtube api to integrate on my website.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is the problem you are having with your code?

Comment: ReferenceError: removeEmptyParams is not defined @JaromandaX

Comment: well, what is that function supposed to be - have you defined it? the comment `// See full sample for function` suggests you've copied this code from somewhere, and haven't bothered to check  "the full sample" for the definition of that function - only you know where you got that 5 line code from

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation page for the youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) shows you small sample snippets. In the top right corner above each code sample there is a small slider. You can use that slider to toggle showing the full code sample. Inside you will find a definition for the `removeEmptyParams`function that was not defined (hence the error message) in your small code snippet and other parts of the code you will need.

You are right that you will need a Youtube api key. [Here you will find information and a small video on obtaining an API key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

xhr request Method for youtube

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",' https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=query&key=yourAPIkey', false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'charset', 'utf-8' );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Accept-Language', '*');
   xhr.send(null);
   xhr_objct = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

it will respond  json object based on your query